# Lower-semicontinuity of quadratic functionals and weak convergence weirdly associated

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Each random variable (rv) considered here is absolutely continuous.

Let $f_{T}$ be a bounded random variable and $T>0$. Suppose we have:

$$f_{T}\rightharpoonup f\tag{1}$$

weakly in probability, which means (by the definition chosen in the proof I read) that for any bounded random variable $\chi$, we have:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\chi f_{T}]=\mathbb{E}[\chi f]$$

They say:

> By the lower-semicontinuity of quadratic functionals and $(1)$, we have:
>   $$\mathbb{E}[f^{2}]\le\liminf_{T\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[f_{T}^{2}]$$

*EDIT: I admit it is a quadratic functional: I had a bad definition.*

I still don't understand how combining lower-semicontinuity and $(1)$ offers the claimed inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of weak convergence you have with $\chi:=f\mathbf 1\{|f|\lt R\}$ where $R$ is fixed. Then we have, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\left(\mathbb E\left[f\cdot f\mathbf 1\left\{|f|\lt R\right\}\right]\right)^2=\lim_{T\to +\infty}\left(\mathbb E\left[f_T\cdot f\mathbf 1\left\{|f|\lt R\right\}\right]\right)^2\leqslant \liminf_{T\to +\infty}\mathbb E\left[f_T^2\right]\cdot \mathbb E\left[f^2\mathbf 1\left\{|f|\lt R\right\}\right].$$
Since it is true for each $R$, we get the result by monotone convergence.

Comment: Thank you :) But why do we need to truncate?

Comment: Because the random variable $\chi$ has to be bounded (and $f$ may not be bounded).

Comment: Right, I missed that point. Thanks a lot!